# Sonar Qubeで解析を手動で実行するには？

Tags: php, laravel, sonarqube

ローカル環境に Sonar Qubeをおき、プロジェクト（laravel）の解析を行ったのですが、プロジェクトの作成時に解析はされるものの（手動での）2回目の解析をする方法が見つかりません。

Sonar Qubeでの解析はCIに導入したものを除き、手動で2回目の解析を行う方法はないのでしょうか？

以下のようなものをTerminalで叩けば良いと思ったのですが、
どこでProjectKeyや、パスワード、設定を見つければ良いかわかりません。

HomebrewでSonarQube　インストールしました。

```
sudo /Users/ddd/Downloads/sonar-scanner-macosx/bin/sonar-scanner 
-Dsonar.projectKey=XXXX
-Dsonar.sources=.  
-Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000   -Dsonar.login=fffb3eb2f45fbbfe24f
```

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 1.263s
INFO: Final Memory: 5M/24M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
ERROR: Not authorized. Analyzing this project requires authentication. Please provide a user token in sonar.login or other credentials in sonar.login and sonar.password.
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

```
% brew install sonar-scanner
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core and homebrew/services).
==> New Formulae
alerter                    doc8                       influxdb-cli               notcurses                  pari-elldata               pyoxidizer                 wildmidi
apt                        docuum                     joplin-cli                 ns-3                       pari-galdata               python-launcher            xauth
aws-vault                  fanyi                      licensefinder              onedrive                   pari-galpol                rsc_2fa                    xsel
bash_unit                  firefoxpwa
...略
Removing: /Users/napmo/Library/Logs/Homebrew/sonarqube... (64B)
==> Upgrading 1 dependent:
sonarqube 9.0.0.45539 -> 9.0.1.46107
==> Upgrading sonarqube
  9.0.0.45539 -> 9.0.1.46107 

sonarqube: The x86_64 architecture is required for this software.
Error: sonarqube: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
==> Checking for dependents of upgraded formulae...
==> No broken dependents found!
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 参考 : https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/overview/

Answer (score 0):

まずは[本家のドキュメント](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/)を読んでいただくことをお勧めします。

そちらを参考にすると

> ProjectKey
> Name of the project that will be displayed on the web interface.

**Webインターフェースに表示されるプロジェクトの名前です。**
プロジェクト単位で解析が可能で、作ったプロジェクトの名前を入れればOKのはずです。

> sonar.login
> The authentication token or login of a SonarQube user with Execute Analysis permission on the project.

**認証のトークンもしくはそのプロジェクトの解析権限を持ったWebログインユーザのID**
認証のトークンの作成の仕方は[こちら](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/user-token/)を参考にしてください。

> sonar.password
> If you're using an authentication token, leave this blank. If you're using a login, this is the password that goes with your sonar.login username.

**もし認証トークンを使う場合は空。

もしWEBログインユーザを利用する場合はそのログイン時のパスワード**

トークンを発行しておけばまずはパスワード不要で解析できるでしょう。